# Firebase: Javascript SDK for push notifications?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, firebase, firebase-notifications

The new version of Firebase supports push notifications.
We can send notifications via the Firebase GUI console.

But does Firebase provide an JavaScript SDK so that I can send notification directly via my web application to my mobile application users?
Because for the moment I am using Firebase as a backend and Parse server for notifications. I would like to use only Firebase.

Answer (score 2):

As per their [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/notifications/), Firebase notification only supports Android and iOS. Hope they would allow this in the future.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to do this with the Web Javascript SDK,

You could send the notification via a [HTTP request](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref).

However, your server key will be needed to authenticate for FCM. It might not be a good idea to include your server key in client code.

From [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options):

> **Important**: Do not include the server key anywhere in your client code. Also, make sure to use only server keys to authorize your app server. Android, iOS, and browser keys are rejected by FCM.